# Lock laptop for 1 hour?

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there anyway to absolutely lock my laptop for one hour? The reason is obvious - to stop procrastination on my part. And by 'absolutely lock' I mean that their is no physical way that I can get onto my desktop.

Comment: I don't think that's possible however you can change the question and say how far you'll go just to get into the desktop

Comment: @DiogoVilela I guess I would go to any length that would take under 10 minutes. A method to get in which is longer I don't think I would bother to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would set an alarm with one of the alarm programs out there and set the title to a randomly typed password you can copy and paste into ubuntu settings. I haven't used any alarms but that's how I would do it on my phone which I assume alarms work the same on Ubuntu

Comment: Not if you don't know the password until the alarm goes off, you can disable Guest btw